# How to make an instance variable refresh on a constant rate in ruby with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, web-applications, sinatra

I'm a total ruby noob, and just wanted to know if it was possible (and how) to make this code:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "#{Time.now}"
end
```

change the time every second?

Basically like the example from here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut2.shtml.
Thanks.

Comment: I would **not** do that server-side...

Comment: How would I do it on the client-side then?

Comment: With javascript just like with the example link

Comment: Is there a way to use erb or stick with ruby to do this? I'm familiar with ruby, but have little experience with javascript.

Comment: If you want to do it on the server side, then you somehow have to implement push-type ajax. I am not sure if you are capable of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not** do this server-side

- It's inefficient - you have to send data over the wire every second
- It's difficult - learning Javascript will be easier than learning all the Ruby tools to make something like this work; and even if you did it server-side you'd probably need to write a fair bit of Javascript to make it work anyways, e.g. if you were to use Juggernaut
- If you're doing web development, it's essentially mandatory to learn Javascript anyways.

You can't have client-side Ruby since browsers don't know how to interpret and execute Ruby.  They know HTML, Javascript, etc.  Cf. [Internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_text)